# How to set up NFS audit options using nfsadmin on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, nfs, audit

Hi guys I need set up two audit options using commandline on bunch of my NFS servers (Windows 2012 R2), like this:

```
nfsadmin server config audit = +mount audit= +locking
```

I pretty sure this is correct syntax, but nfsadmin commandline tool thinks different:

```
Invalid option argument.
Usage : nfsadmin [server | client | mapping ] [\\host]
For detailed help type nfsadmin [server|client|mapping] /?
```

This is a question, because seems like Microsoft change nfsadmin's syntax in latest OSes, but forgot to update guides.

So, maybe exist another way to change this settings, instead of using GUI of course.

Comment: I found worked solution: 

nfsadmin server config activity=+mount +locking